# c++ Distributed computing of an executable program

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

I was wondering if it is possible to run an executable program without adding to its source code, like running any game across several computers. When i was programming in c# i noticed a process method, which lets you summon or close any application or process, i was wondering if there was something similar with c++ which would let me transfer the processes of any executable file or game to other computers or servers minimizing my computer's processor consumption.

thanks.

Comment: Would you call it load balancing if everyone in the office played Minesweeper at once?

Comment: no, i was referring to running minesweeper using other people's processing power and very little of my own.

Comment: What about Terminal Server, Remote Desktop or VNC?

Comment: i'm gonna run it through my servers.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is possible, but this would require a huge amount of work and would almost for sure make your program painfully slower (I'm talking about a factor of millions or billions here). Essentially you would need to make sure every layer that is used in the program allows this. So you'd have to rewrite the OS to be able to do this, but also quite a few of the libraries it uses.

Why? Let's assume you want to distribute actual threads over different machines. It would be *slightly* more easy if it were actual processes, but I'd be surprised many applications work like this.

To begin with, you need to synchronize the memory, more specifically all non-thread-local storage, which often means 'all memory' because not all language have a thread-aware memory model. Of course, this can be optimized, for example buffer everything until you encounter an 'atomic' read or write, if of course your system has such a concept. Now can you imagine every thread blocking for synchronization a few seconds whenever a thread has to be locked/unlocked or an atomic variable has to be read/written?

Next to that there are the issues related to managing devices. Assume you need a network connection: which device will start this, how will the ip be chosen, ...? To seamlessly solve this you probably need a virtual device shared amongst all platforms. This has to happen for network devices, filesystems, printers, monitors, ... . And as you kindly mention games: this should happen for a GPU as well, just imagine how this would impact performance in only sending data from/to the GPU (hint: even 16xpci-e is often already a bottleneck).

In conclusion: this is not feasible, if you want a clustered application, you have to build it into the application from scratch.

Comment: no atomic concepts, i am planning on just running a game on my computer using my other computers i have lying around.

Comment: @user1509326: a multithreaded application will have some synchronisation variables (locks, atomics, signals, ...) that you can't get around. duplicating the cpu work seamlessly over multiple machines is nearly impossible. The best you can do is to hook DirectX or OpenGL and distribute those calls to other machines, but even that will cause your performance to drop usually (I did this as an experiment in my master dissertation, that was about offloading games to a network server).

Comment: Of course, you can always run the game at one computer (still one) and use nx or vnc or a similar technology to see and control it from another. but typically these technologies do not work very well out-of-the-box for games (the screens change to frequently), so you need a lot of bandwidth and usually also a lot of processing power extra to encode the streams on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the closest thing you can do is [MapReduce](http://www.craighenderson.co.uk/mapreduce/): it's a paradigm which hopefully will be a part of the official boost library soon. However, I don't think that you would want to apply it to a real-time application like a game.

A related question may provide more answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168558/is-there-anything-like-hadoop-in-c

But as KillianDS pointed out, there is no [automagical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/automagical) way to do this, nor does it seem like is there a feasible way to do it. So what is the exact problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: Map and reduce operations have been available for C++ in the OpenMP library for decades. The version used by Google is only one of many possible ways of breaking up a problem, and in particular is not a good means for something requiring timely responses such as a game.

Answer (score 0):

The current state of research is into practical means to distribute the work of a process across multiple CPU cores on a single computer. In that case, these processors still share RAM. This is essential: RAM latencies are measured in nanoseconds.

In distributed computing, remote memory access can take tens if not hundreds of microseconds. Distributed algorithms explicitly take this into account. No amount of magic can make this disappear: light itself is slow.

Answer (score 0):

The [Plan 9 OS](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/plan9/) from AT&T Bell Labs supports distributed computing in the most seamless and transparent manner. Plan 9 was designed to take the Unix ideas of breaking jobs into interoperating small tasks, performed by highly specialised utilities, and "everything is a file", as well as the client/server model, to a whole new level. It has the idea of a CPU server which performs computations for less powerful networked clients. Unfortunately the idea was too ambitious and way beyond its time and Plan 9 remained largerly a research project. It is still being developed as open source software though.

MOSIX is another distributed OS project that provides a single process space over multiple machines and supports transparent process migration. It allows processes to become migratable without any changes to their source code as all context saving and restoration are done by the OS kernel. There are several implementations of the MOSIX model - MOSIX2, openMosix (discontinued since 2008) and LinuxPMI (continuation of the openMosix project).

ScaleMP is yet another commercial Single System Image (SSI) implementation, mainly targeted towards data processing and Hight Performance Computing. It not only provides transparent migration between the nodes of a cluster but also provides emulated shared memory (known as Distributed Shared Memory). Basically it transforms a bunch of computers, connected via very fast network, into a single big NUMA machine with many CPUs and huge amount of memory.

None of these would allow you to launch a game on your PC and have it transparently migrated and executed somewhere on the network. Besides most games are GPU intensive and not so much CPU intensive - most games are still not even utilising the full computing power of multicore CPUs. We have a ScaleMP cluster here and it doesn't run Quake very well...